# Keep company name on its own line on company page

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

I've ran into around 5-7 of these companies that have a fairly long name:

[image]

This one is actually not that bad, there is much worse.  The site ends up getting covered and in some cases the job number.  My proposal is to keep the actual company name in its own div allowing the rest of the content to go directly above or below the company name.  In some cases the website url name is really long, do we really need to give the actual website name, how about just a visit website link for all companies?

Answer (score 1):

Company Page redesigns are a long time coming. This issue crops up and really can't be fixed without a complete overhaul of the page. We do have upcoming plans regarding company pages that should fix this issue.